# building jenkins pipeline in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, jenkins, mocha.js, chai

I need to implement this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'python:2-alpine'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'qnib/pytest'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'py.test --verbose --junit-xml test-reports/results.xml sources/test_calc.py'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'test-reports/results.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on a nodejs express project and run unit tests with mocha and chai,
this is my code :

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:6.3' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how I should do that? the example is with python so I have no idea what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the resources on the Jenkins blog. What you are looking at is the Jenkinsfile which sits in the root of your project directory.

https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/